# Can an HDMI receiver device recover after TDMS lines are cut-off for long period?

Tags: hdmi, video-transmitter

I'm trying to gauge the viability of making an HDMI multiplexer/demultiplexer for multiple lines. The main goal is to be able to switch various inputs to various outputs.

This question in particular is about attempting to make so the hdmi host (the device outputting the video data) never becomes aware that it's been disconnected (desireable for instance with windows, as windows will rearrange your desktop and windows if detects a monitor has been disconnected).

As far as I can understand it, the TDMS channels are unidirectional. And from what I've seen HDMI switch ICs are basically just high frequency analog switches. So my thought then was "what if I can just use a microcontroller to simulate the 5V line and DDC communications, and then use the switch IC to route the TDMS lines to where I want them?".

In that way I hoped I might be able to keep the host transmitting data on the TDMS lines, blissfully unaware it wasn't actually getting to the monitor.
The problem would be when switching that signal line back to the monitor. I could simulate disconnecting the hdmi cable, connecting it again and re-negotiating everything with the previously recorded DDC data from the host.. but as soon as I switch back the TDMS lines, there's no telling what the device would start receiving (it would likely start receiving the middle of a frame, probably mid-packet, completely unrecognizable).

So, would a receiver device be tolerant to missing a large portion of the data it was supposed to receive? Does HDMI specify a way for the receiver to "find the start of the next frame" in the case it completely loses synchronization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure it can resync so locking on to TMDS and video stream is not a problem as that happens anyway when you plug in the connector, the video starts at whatever random point after link has been negotiated.

But depending on if you are using HDCP or HDMI 2.0 or HDMI 2.1 protocols, the DDC link is used to verify they are OK, so the PC will surely know the display was disconnected even if you keep HPD high.

Just use a software solution; force your PC to not care about disconnection. Most video drivers allow this.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading your answer. I was asking about *keeping* the DDC link up "manually" (via a microcontroller "in the middle" for instance) while switching "off" *only* the TDMS channels. E.g. connect host A to screen -> disconnect host from screen but simulate DDC link (and HDP and 5v) so host A thinks it's still connected -> connect and eventually disconnect some other host B -> renegociate DDC with monitor with recorded data from host A -> go back to passing DDC through and switch in the TDMS lines to the monitor. For host A it would be as if the monitor never disconnected.

Comment: Yes, that is impossible, you can't keep DDC link up as HDCP, HDMI 2.0 TMDS scrambling and HDMI 2.1 FRL need re-negotiatios if you lose the link - it can't continue as if nothing happened. A software solution on PC is possible, hardware isn't.

Comment: How about no HDCP, or HDMI version prior to 2.0, could it work? 
Also could you provide some source for the software solution? I've been looking for a bit now and I can't find much. The most that I've been able to find is about disabling hot-plug detection via windows registry.

Comment: Sure, no HDCP and limiting resolution to fit below HDMI 2.0 requirements of 340 MHz might work. But many source devices are able to sense the TMDS line disconnection. Disabling the hotplug detection should work to fake the display is always present so monitor config does not change. Most video drivers have such feature.